# Why Angular doesn't show errors on screen?

Tags: html, angular, web, frontend, console.log

I have a TypeScript-Angular project that includes the following packages:

```
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1202.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         12.2.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.2.2 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          12.2.2 (cli-only)
```

I am getting an error message when I run the project, but it only shows via `console.log`. I'd like to the them on my screen, because it is encoded to render with the HTML.

[image]

Is this caused by an improper configuration?

My main.ts

[image]

Comment: Can you share your main.ts ?

Comment: ```typescript
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: What are you, a caveman? Please use the edit feature to update your question when adding code (especially when your adding an entire TS file). Jeezzz...

Answer (score 0):

Angular now uses by default the AOT (Ahead of Time) Compiler, which optimizes your page during compile time. Your code seems to have some issues, which crashes the compilation, and therefore Angular is not able to generate the JavaScript.

You can try to disable the AOT compilation in your `angular.json` below `architect/build/options` by adding `aot: false`. But I do not recommend to do this for production builds!

You can learn more about the AOT Compiler here:
https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Comment: Thankss!
I just want to see my erros on page and not on console

Comment: To confirm this do you do do `npm start` or `ng build & ng serve`

Comment: `npm start` is usually a alias for `ng serve`. There is no need for `ng build` before.

Comment: Sorry you are correct, Your initial answer though was suggesting that he was doing a build, using AOT. Doesn't angular 12 still uses JIT mode for ng serve though ?